# What storage is suitable

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, performance, amazon-s3, storage

I come across a use case were I have to store around 200 kb of JSON object.

But I am not sure where to store the same. is it feasible to store in MySql column or should store it in S3 ? What I know is if I store it in MySql then retrieval would be faster but may be storage cost will be higher.

Please help me what storage should I use.

Comment: How many of them do you need to store? Just 1 x 200kb, or thousands, or...? How will the JSON object be used? Is there a speed requirement? Please edit your question to tell us A LOT more about your actual use-case, so we can provide a suitable recommendation.

Comment: Yes John, there will be thousands to store and yes there is speed requirement, I need to read this json on user request from browser. User could not wait while the time I am reading this JSON. So I am looking for a solution where storage cost is low and reading is faster.

Comment: What do you mean by "read this json on user request from browser"? Please edit your question to provide FULL details of your intended use-case, otherwise we can't really advise you on the best choice. Let us know things like how the data is being accessed (from where?), how it is being queried (is it via a unique ID?), why speed is important, and why it is being stored in JSON (or can it be converted to normal columns in a database?). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

MySQL would probably be the most expensive option, it would also add a lot of management overhead if you weren't using [Amazon Aurora Serverless](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/serverless/).

You could use Amazon S3 which would have the lowest cost. If you have to rely on very low read latency at a slightly higher cost, you could also use [Amazon DynamoDB](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/), which allows a maximum item size of 200 KB.

Comment: I thought of using S3 at first but than I thought reading from S3 would be slower comparatively, do you suggest reading from S3 at user request ?

Comment: Yes, I would suggest storing it in S3. It is the simplest and most cost-effective solution. Retrieval from S3 is quite quick. Certainly, there are purpose-built storage solutions for very low-latency scenarios, like Amazon DynamoDB or Amazon Elasticache (MySQL is not necessarily one of them). So if it turns out that S3's retrieval times are insufficient, you can consider using DynamoDB or maybe a relational database with ElastiCache. But that would be more work, at a higher cost, so it's up to you how much you want to optimize.

Answer (score 0):

I would store it in a column in the table.  That column would be of type `MEDIUMBLOB` and it would not be JSON, but rather a compressed copy of the JSON string.  Furthermore, I would do the compression/decompression in the client, so as to decrease the network delay.

`COMPRESS()` of `JSON` gives about 3x shrinkage.  That is, the 200KB will take only about 70KB on disk and across the network.

I am assuming you have a key to the *one* row that you want for the given user?

(No, I don't know how to factor in the lack of S3 savings, nor do I know the network latency and bandwidth.)